# Можно ли, с помощью MyQuery получить всю таблицу разом?

Tags: mysql, delphi

я хочу получить список поддерживаемых языков из таблицы

```
id  lang
1 ru
2 en
3 gr

  for I := 1 to 8 do
  begin
    MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM languages WHERE id = "' + IntToStr(i) + '"');
    MyQuery1.ExecSQL;
    iStrig := iStrig + '"' + MyQuery1.Fields[1] + '",';
  end;
```

как мне сделать, что бы один раз обратиться к базе, а потом, в цикле перебирать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM languages');
MyQuery1.Open;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  iStrig := iStrig + '"' + MyQuery1.FieldByName('lang').AsString + '",';
  MyQuery1.Next;
end;
```